# PHP 7.3.x to PHP 7.4.x upgrade is not happening successfully

Tags: php, upgrade

Previous version : 7.3.9
New version : 7.4.13

We do compile PHP from source and downloaded source from http://php.net/get/php-7.4.13.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror .
And the compilation configuration are below

```
  ./configure \
  --prefix=/opt/php \
  --with-apxs2=/opt/apache/bin/apxs \
  --with-ldap=/opt/openldap \
  --enable-soap \
  --enable-sockets \
  --with-pgsql=/opt/php/pgsql \
  --with-pdo-pgsql=/opt/php/pgsql \
  --with-mysql \
  --with-pdo-mysql \
  --enable-gd \
  --with-jpeg \
  --with-freetype \
  --enable-gd-native-ttf \
  --enable-pcntl \
  --with-openssl \
  --with-openssl-dir=/opt/libressl \
  --with-curl \
  --enable-mbstring \
  --with-mcrypt \
  --with-config-file-path=/opt/php/etc \
  --with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/php/etc/php.d \
  --with-zip \
  --with-xsl \
  --without-libzip \
  --with-pear=/opt/php/bin
```

Now this installation is not proper it seems .
Before 7.4.13 i see lot of utility directory present in /opt/php/lib/php/ like XML,,Mail,PEAR but after 7.4.13 i am not seeing those.

Is there any additional parameter we need to pass to install those on lib directory .
The only discrepancy i am seeing for openssl warning: libssl.so.10, needed by /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libssl.so.48

Can someone please help in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

For me --with-curl was creating the issue, in PHP 7.3.x we have option to provide curl directory which is remove in 7.4.X(7.4.13 what i am working currently). So we had to set CFLAGS and LDFLAGS before configure

```
CFLAGS ="-I/opt/curl/include"
LDFLAGS =" -L/opt/curl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/curl/lib"
```